# Qemu fails to start

Tags: arch-linux, qemu, pci-passthrough

So I've been trying to set up GPU passthrough on Arch, but I've ran into a wall.

I followed these two guides, mostly the first one though: [GPU Passthrough Revisited](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/3lno0t/gpu_passthrough_revisited_an_updated_guide_on_how/), [Non-root GPU passthrough](https://www.evonide.com/non-root-gpu-passthrough-setup/).

I did each step exactly as described, and everything worked as described. Then, when I got the part where I have to start QEMU, it doesn't work. I successfully bound my GPU to vfio, but now I'm stuck. Here's the output of `lspci -nnk` for my GPU.

```
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] [10de:139a] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:178d]
    Kernel driver in use: vfio-pci
    Kernel modules: nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

But then when I try to start qemu, I get this output:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
QEMU 2.9.0 monitor - type 'help' for more information
(qemu) gtk initialization failed
```

The `MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE` can be fixed by setting the `WINDOW` variable, but I still can't start up QEMU.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It could be easier if you would provide full command you ran. Anyway, I suppose you tried to run QEMU VM (with GTK display output) as root (or any other user not using current X11 session). Try `xhost +local:<user_running_qemu>`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this works:

```bash
DISPLAY=:0 <command>
```